# How to set up multilingual text to speech

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I'm working on an android Studio project, requiring text to speech. 
I would like to implement a program which can recognize in which language the text is written and read it with the appropriate pronunciation.

Example : if i have a text in English, i want the application to pronounce it in English with the English pronunciation.

Is it possible ?

Thank you

I have successfully implemented TTS in French and it works fine.

```
    mTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                int result = mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.FRENCH);

                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                        || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("TTS", "Language not supported");
                } else {
                    mButtonSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("TTS", "Initialization failed");
            }
        }
    });
```

I would like to have a multilingual text to speech app

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the language of a text with [**Android ML Kit**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/identify-languages)

Add the dependencies for the ML Kit Android libraries to your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually `app/build.gradle`):

```
dependencies {
  // ...

  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-language:20.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-language-language-id-model:20.0.0'
}
```

To identify the language of a string, get an instance of FirebaseLanguageIdentification, and then pass the string to the `identifyLanguage()`method.

For example:

```
FirebaseLanguageIdentification languageIdentifier =
        FirebaseNaturalLanguage.getInstance().getLanguageIdentification();
languageIdentifier.identifyLanguage(text)
      .addOnSuccessListener(
          new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@Nullable String languageCode) {
              if (languageCode != "und") {
                Log.i(TAG, "Language: " + languageCode);
              } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Can't identify language.");
              }
            }
          })
      .addOnFailureListener(
          new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
              // Model couldn’t be loaded or other internal error.
              // ...
            }
          });
```